# Casting and Adding list in one line

Tags: c#, casting

Is it possible to write the following code in one line;

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load((IDataReader)obj);
dataTables.Add(dt);
```

where `dataTables` is a list:

```
IList<DataTable> dataTables = new List<DataTable>();
```

I tried following, but it doesn't work;

```
dataTables.Add(new DataTable().Load((IDataReader)obj));
```

Error (which is very understandable):

> Cannot convert `void` to `System.Data.DataTable`

Comment: " (which is very understandable):" you actually answered your own question. No, it is not, because `Load` does not return anything, so you cannot pump is into the `Add` method as parameter. You can do it using a lambda expression but this would only masking 2 statements as 1 in one line. Not really a suitable solution that I would suggest

Comment: The first code sample is going to be easier to read and understand than any attempt to do it in a single line. _A lambda or extension method may be worth considering, if you really want to do so._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the `Load` method returns void so you cannot cast it back to a `DataTable`.

But you could write your own LoadReader extension method that returns back the DataTable:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public DataTable LoadReader(this DataTable dt, IDataReader reader)
    {
        dt.Load(reader);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
dataTables.Add(new DataTable().LoadReader((IDataReader)obj));
```

Comment: So, it's not possible in the C# language itself. 

I thought, there could be a way that C# compiler would be smart enough that if the Load() method (or any other methods on any other classes) called with an already defined instance, then it should just load otherwise if it's called  with the 'new' operator, it should load and return the new instance.

Thanks for your (@Alberto) answer though.